# Is it idiomatic to panic in From implementations?

Tags: rust, idioms

The documentation at https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html states

> Note: This trait must not fail. If the conversion can fail, use TryFrom.

Suppose I have a `From` implementation thus:

```rust
impl From<SomeStruct> for http::Uri {
    fn from(item: SomeStruct) -> http::Uri {
        item.uri.parse::<http::Uri>() // can fail
    }
}
```

Further suppose I am completely certain that `item.uri.parse` will succeed. Is it idiomatic to panic in this scenario? Say, with:

```rust
item.uri.parse::<http::Uri>().unwrap()
```

In this particular case, it appears there's no way to construct an HTTP URI at compile time: https://docs.rs/http/0.2.5/src/http/uri/mod.rs.html#117. In the real scenario `.uri` is an associated const, so I can test all used values parse. But it seems to me there could be other scenarios when the author is confident in the infallibility of a piece of code, particularly when that confidence can be encoded in tests, and would therefore prefer the ergonomics of `From` over `TryFrom`. The Rust compiler, typically quite strict, doesn't prevent this behaviour, though it seems it perhaps could. This makes me think this is a decision the author has been deliberately allowed to make. So the question is asking: what do people tend to do in this situation?

Comment: Even if this can't fail in a robust application I would avoid this. There is no reason to not handle the error correctly like any other error in your code.

Comment: The general rule is that you should only panic for programming errors. If a panic occurs, your program has a bug that needs to be fixed. This rule applies to implementing the `From` trait as well. If `SomeStruct` guarantees that the `uri` field always parses as a valid URI, no matter how `SomeStruct` is used, then panicking in the `From` trait is fine, since any panic would indicate that `SomeStruct` is not upholding it's guarantee that `uri` is always valid.

Comment: Well, @Stargateur, I propose that there is a reason: every single user of your API has to put up with poorer ergonomics for something that you (and probably they) are completely confident will never occur. Having said that, I definitely respect your perspective: if it's handled like anything else, then it will *certainly* never be anyone's problem. Anyway, this isn't a hill I'd die on, which is why I'm asking what other people think! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @mkingston Well, if you are confident enough. Without full context it's hard to give more than a general advice.

Comment: Unwrap and other panic-y things are fine if you know it will succeed. So if the URI is built into your library/binary, it's fine, but if it's user-provided (or if it's a lib, user-of-lib provided), absolutely not ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in general, traits only enforce that the implementors adhere to the signatures and types as laid out in the trait. At least that's what the compiler enforces.

On top of that, there are certain *contracts* that traits are *expected* to adhere to just so that there's no weird surprises by those who work with these traits. These contracts aren't checked by the compiler; that would be quite difficult.

Nothing prevents you from implementing all a trait's methods but in way that's totally unrelated to what the trait is all about, like implementing the `Display` trait but then in the `fmt` method not actually bothering to use `write!` and instead, I don't know, delete the user's home directory.

Now back to your specific case. If your `from` method will not fail, provably so, then of course you can use `.unwrap`. The point of the `cannot fail` contract for the `From` trait is that those who rely on the `From` trait want to be able to assume that the conversion will go through *every time*. If you *actually* panic in your own implementation of `from`, it means the conversion sometimes *doesn't* go through, counter to the ideas and contracts in the `From` trait.

Comment: It might be worth noting that many `From` implementations might panic in extreme circumstances — for example, failing to allocate memory in order to copy data into a new layout, or (in practice if not ideally) some edge case in representable data with large numbers.

Comment: @KevinReid that's a good addendum: if I were allocating in my `From` implementation, there's an opportunity to panic already, it's not something that's otherwise impossible.

Comment: @Lagerbaer great point "in general, traits only enforce [...]" i.e. my supposition that "the compiler could reject a panic" is perhaps pedantically correct, but predicated on my assumption that the compiler _cares_ what I do in my implementation. "Cannot panic" was not in the type of the implementation, nor is it the compiler's job in general to check that, therefore why would it care for my specific `From` impl. I was definitely laser focused on my particular case, but this is a good piece of "bigger picture" feedback, thank you.